# Are there security design weaknesses in the EFF Sovereign Keys proposal?

Tags: certificate-authority

In response to SOPA and a number of high profile security breaches at certficate authourities in 2011, the EFF has released a soverign keys proposal:

https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2011/11/sovereign-keys-proposal-make-https-and-email-more-secure

As a security community can we see any design flaws and proposed changes in this proposal that we could feedback?

Comment: FYI, the [EFF has already started collecting issues on the protocol](https://git.eff.org/?p=sovereign-keys.git;a=tree;f=issues;h=cfd69959ba027e7ecaccfb482ea69dfd7525c819;hb=HEAD). As expected, they revolve around DoS attacks on the storage and network resources as well as around the distributed nature of the protocol itself. Distributed protocols are hard -- let alone distributed security protocols, and I think this is where the design will fall down the most.

Comment: Some of us might even be working on it, but I doubt this website is the right place to post research results and discuss potential flaws of a *proposal*.

Comment: @e-sushi - although I understand you may be working on it and not able to comment, but encouraging analysis and comment from individuals in the industry **has** to be a good thing.

Comment: @Rory : that's true, and please don't misunderstand - I am all for it. I just think it's to be noted (as Greg indicated) that there is a centralized place to discuss such things. Discussing potential weaknesses in public isn't always *the safe way to do it*. That's all. ;)

Comment: @E-sushi Do you have a link to that discussion place?

Comment: No, not one that I can share here.

Comment: Some concerns I have: 1) Who would actually be building/maintaining the timeline and mirror servers? How would you prevent them from getting access to the key material? 2)What is to prevent me from building a replica timeline or mirror for the sole purpose of stealing the key material?

Comment: @e-sushi well done i hope the proposal is progressing well. The more the Eff gets involved with this the better

Comment: You can follow some of the identified issues as they make it into the proposal stored on EFF's git server: https://git.eff.org/?p=sovereign-keys.git;a=tree;f=issues;hb=HEAD

Answer (score 1):

this piece bugs me...

> In practice, we expect many domains to use a third-party service
>   provider for Sovereign Key management,3 but the domain holders can
>   choose exactly which if any such parties they wish to trust.

So there will be a handful of Sovereign Key Management (SKM) companies similar to the handful of Certificate root companies now. They will charge an exorbidant fee to store your Key for you, and half the websites won't do it. THEN the browsers will (instead of blocking the invalid key) have to default to a "The Sovereign Key for the website you are attempting to access is invalid. Would you like to continue to the website anyway?"

How is this different from what we have now?